# android dev open a file through os

Tags: android, android-intent

hi is there a way to ask the os to open a file with its predefined programm?

I do not know what kind of file it might be, maybe a photo , txt anything.
I want to issue a command to the os to ask it to open the file(i have the filepath) with any program the os wants. It might be the case that the os opens the dialog asking the user to select one program to open the file(that is fine with me).

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done through an `Intent` You will need to set the action and the data.

```
//from inside an Activity
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.fromFile(theFileYouMentioned));
try{
  startActivity(i);
}
catch(ActivityNotFoundException) {
   //user doesn't have an app that can open this type of file
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do that via an intent chooser:

please refer to : http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html